# Selenium IDE XPath: waitForElementNotPresent with not operator doesn't work

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I have a problem with a `XPath` in Selenium IDE.

I have a table where are some records in it. On top of the table headers I have some filtering dropdown menus and a funnel icon, which calls an AJAX function and give's me back the filtered data. Now the problem is, Selenium IDE doesn't recognize when the AJAX call has finished.

Now, when I'm creating the element, I'm looking for it with the following WORKING `XPath`:

waitForElementPresent

```
//tr[td/text()='${partyStatus}' and td/text()='${partyLabel}']
```

When deleting, the status get changed to Inactive. Then i filter for all inactive elements with the same 'partyLabel'.

Then i want to wait for all other elements which are NOT having the actual partyState (inactive) and are not the same partyLabel to not be present

First, I tried this:

waitForElementNotPresent

```
//tr[td/text()!='${partyStatus}' and td/text()!='${partyLabel}']
```

This did not work. Then I tried this one, which didn't worked either:

```
//tr[not(td/text()!='${partyStatus}') and not(td/text()='${partyLabel}')]
```

Now, I'm stuck here to get this working. How can I wait for the elements to disappear which have the other state and are not the same `partyLabel` like this one I'm looking for.

Here's an example of one table row:

`PartyLabel` is first `td` element and `partyStatus` is second to last `td` element.

```
<tr id="mf:searchAdministrable:0_row_0">
    <td style="width:10%">Trader</td>
    <td style="width: 2%;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span id="mf:searchAdministrable:0:j_idt90">Not Started</span></td>
    <td style="width:10%">0570-123456-4</td>
    <td style="width: 8%;">142223</td>
    <td style="width: 26%;">John Doe #4</td>
    <td style="width:15%;"><span id="mf:searchAdministrable:0:j_idt107"><span id="mf:searchAdministrable:0:j_idt107"> United Kingdom</span></span>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width:8%">SNG</td>
    <td style="width:9%;">Inactive</td>
    <td style="width: 12%;"><a onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('mf'),{'mf:searchAdministrable:0:edit':'mf:searchAdministrable:0:edit'},'');return false" href="#" id="mf:searchAdministrable:0:edit"><img width="16" height="16" src="/skinned/javax.faces.resource/com.csg.jsf.resources.icons/skin/csstandard12/ico_edit_16_cli.gif?conversationContext=j&amp;transactionToken=0.6158652516940941" alt="ico_edit" id="mf:searchAdministrable:0:editIcon"></a><a onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('mf'),{'mf:searchAdministrable:0:delete':'mf:searchAdministrable:0:delete'},'');return false" href="#" id="mf:searchAdministrable:0:delete"><img width="16" height="16" src="/skinned/javax.faces.resource/com.csg.jsf.resources.icons/skin/csstandard12/ico_delete_16_cli.gif?conversationContext=j&amp;transactionToken=0.6158652516940941" alt="ico_delete" id="mf:searchAdministrable:0:deleteIcon"></a><a onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('mf'),{'mf:searchAdministrable:0:screen':'mf:searchAdministrable:0:screen'},'');return false" title="Screen Transaction Not Started" href="#" id="mf:searchAdministrable:0:screen"><img width="16px" height="16px" src="/images/ico_worldcheck.gif?conversationContext=j&amp;transactionToken=0.6158652516940941" id="mf:searchAdministrable:0:screenIcon"></a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

The element might still be present within the HTML, but just hidden. Try using waitForVisible and waitForNotVisible instead

Comment: No de table get reloaded coplete. The element is gone after that. Also in the html source.